# Powershell - Using Config Files for Variables

Tags: command-line, powershell

I need to build a set of scripts in PowerShell for SharePoint Deployments, and I'd like to use the same idea I've been using in BAT files.

The idea is having ONE .ps1 to configure "session" variables, example: `[string] $SiteUrl`,
and then call first this config script in each .ps1 file I have, so I just need to edit one.

### Config.ps1

```
[string] $SiteUrl = "www.google.com"
[string] $WspPath = "C:\path\to\wsp.wsp"
```

### Deploy.ps1

```
INVOKE Config.ps1 --> ?????????????
STSADM -o addsolution $SiteUrl
```

How can I manage that in PowerShell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just dot source the config.ps1 script:

```
. .\Config.ps1
```

And then you can just call the variables when you need them.

```
$SiteUrl
$WspPath
```

Answer (score -1):

Please consider, that if an attacker can modify the external ps1 file, he can make really mess. for example what happens if he changes this:

[string] $SiteUrl = "www.google.com"
[string] $WspPath = "C:\path\to\wsp.wsp"

to this:
[string] $SiteUrl = "www.google.com"
[string] $WspPath = "C:\path\to\wsp.wsp"
format c: